# Can't redeploy application (using JAXB)

Tags: tomcat, jaxb

I can't redeploy my application on Tomcat 7 on Windows.  It attempts to undeploy the app but one file cannot be deleted: 
`jaxb-impl-2.1.13.jar`.  I then cannot deploy the app again because the file is present.

If I restart Tomcat, I can deploy the app.

This is what I get in the log:

```
Oct 08, 2013 12:00:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
INFO: Undeploying context [/myApp]
Oct 08, 2013 12:00:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
SEVERE: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF\lib] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
Oct 08, 2013 12:00:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
SEVERE: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myApp\WEB-INF] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
Oct 08, 2013 12:00:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar deleteDir
SEVERE: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myApp] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
Oct 08, 2013 12:00:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar delete
SEVERE: [C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\myApp] could not be completely deleted. The presence of the remaining files may cause problems
```

I don't get this problem on Linux, only on Windows.  How can I release this file so I can redeploy my app?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem also on Linux, and on Tomcat 6.0.32. I see that launch the "find leaks" function, then re-undeploying the webapp can partially resolve the problem (the jar can be removed but the classes remain loaded in memory).

Comment: Same problem here as well... Windows 7 64 bit and tomcat 6.0.35. Even using the find leaks function and attempting another undeploy, the jar stays where it is.

Answer (score 5):

I just get clear about this problem. For the reason about locking issue, you could check [apache wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Windows#Q5).

One of the way to resolve this problem is configuring the following properties of `Context` tag in `context.xml`:

- `antiJARLocking="true"`
- `antiResourceLocking="true"`

Comment: FYI from [Tomcat docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html): "antiJARLocking is a subset of antiResourceLocking and therefore, to prevent duplicate work and possible issues, only one of these attributes should be set to true at any one time"